# How to send status of scheduled script via mail?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have created a simple PowerShell script for log file move from source to destination with log_present date. This report can be captured through mail notification?

```
Move-Item C:\Users\hxsabe\Desktop\Test\Success_Login.txt H:\Downloads\test

Rename-Item H:\Downloads\test\Success_Login.txt "Success_Login_$(Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy").txt"
```

This script has to be scheduled in Windows scheduled task after completion of this script email notification is required by success/failed task.

Comment: Have a look at send-mailmessage or the Net.Mail.MailMessage object.
You can copy your file directly to the filename with date from the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` to enforce terminating errors, run your statements in a `try..catch` block, and put a `Send-MailMessage` statement in a `finally` clause.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
  $src = 'C:\Users\hxsabe\Desktop\Test\Success_Login.txt'
  $dst = "H:\Downloads\test\Success_Login_$(Get-Date -Format 'ddMMyyyy').txt"
  Move-Item $src $dst

  $msg = 'Move successful.'
} catch {
  $msg = 'Move failed.'
} finally {
  Send-MailMessage -Subject $msg -Body $msg ...
}
```

Or check the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$?` to see if the previous operation was successful:

```
$src = 'C:\Users\hxsabe\Desktop\Test\Success_Login.txt'
$dst = "H:\Downloads\test\Success_Login_$(Get-Date -Format 'ddMMyyyy').txt"

Move-Item $src $dst

$msg = if ($?) { 'Move successful.' } else { 'Move failed.' }

Send-MailMessage -Subject $msg -Body $msg ...
```

Comment: Help me on that if I am saving as a PS1 file and running under powershell command getting error plz help me below is the error.





At line:1 char:26
+ C:\Users\hxsabe\Desktop\R&D\Sucess_Move_Report.ps1
+                          ~
Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to
pass ampersand as a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed

Comment: PowerShell doesn't like the ampersand in your path. Put the path in quotes and use the call operator to run the script: `& "C:\path\to\your.ps1"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy"
$Source = "C:\Users\hxsabe\Desktop\Test"
$Destination = "H:\Downloads\test"

move-item $Source\Success_Login.txt $Destination
Rename-Item $Destination\Success_Login.txt "Success_Login_$($Date).txt"

if(Test-Path $Destination\"Success_Login_$($Date).txt")
{
    Send-Mailmessage -smtp x.x.com -from x@x.com -to y@x.com -subject "My Subject"`
                     -Body "Logging successfull"
}
else 
{
    Send-Mailmessage -smtp x.x.com -from x@x.com -to y@x.com -subject "My Subject"`
                     -Body "Logging NOT successfull"
}
```

You can test if the file exist with `Test-Path` and then it will send an E-Mail if it was successfull or not successfull.